# jQuery Tools tabs – changing background color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tools, flowplayer

I'm using this set-up:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/slideshow.htm

I would like to change the BODY background when switching from tab to tab, with one specific color to match each tab.

Could someone let me know what additional code I'd need to add?

I would be grateful for any help, because I'm not fluent with JS at all, although I'm quite good with HTML/CSS ;)

Many thanks.

Comment: Yes you can customize the tabs as required but this is not "give me the code site".You can try understanding the css and javascript code for the plugin and if any doubt you can ask.We are ready to help when you are stuck.Copying the code from the answers will not help you to learn.

Comment: I'm not asking about customizing the tabs. I'm asking about applying a specific color to the page (body) when switching tabs. I don't think this is anything I can 'explore' and therefore try to understand with jQuery Tools, because it's not part of it.

As it is, I am stuck. As I have explained, I'm an absolute beginner with JS, and for that I apologize. Not sure what else I cand do other than ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should take a look at the [events documentation](http://flowplayer.org/tools/documentation/scripting.html#events).

My guess is to bind to `onClick` and/or `onBeforeClick` and probably use a `data-bgColor="#FFF"`-type attribute on each tab, then locate (and apply) that value to the body's background on one of those events. Something like:

```
<!-- first slide -->
<div data-bgcolor="#FF0000"> ... </div>

<!-- second slide -->
<div data-bgcolor="#00FF00"> ... </div>

<!-- third slide -->
<div data-bgcolor="#0000FF"> ... </div>
```

And:

```
$('.tabs').tabs(".images > div", {
  // ...
  // other properties applied
  // ...

  onBeforeClick: function(event,tabIndex){
    // /* pseudo-code */
    // var bg = $(event.element).data('bgcolor');
    // $('body').css('background-color', bg);
  }
});
```